# Message sending in Erlang under the hood

Tags: erlang

Message sending in Erlang is *asynchronous*, meaning that a send expression such as `PidB ! msg` evaluated by a process `PidA` immediately yields the result `msg` without blocking the latter. Naturally, its side effect is that of *sending* `msg` to `PidB`.

Since this mode of message passing does *not* provide any message delivery guarantees, the sender must itself ascertain whether a message has been actually delivered by asking the recipient to confirm accordingly. After all, confirming whether a message has been delivered might not always be required.

This holds true in both the local and distributed cases: in the latter scenario, the sender cannot simply assume that the remote node is always available; in the local scenario, where processes live on the same Erlang node, a process may send a message to a non-existent process.

---

I am curious as to how the side effect portion of `!`, *i.e*, message sending, works at the VM-level when the sender and recipient processes live on the **same** node. In particular, I would like to know whether the sending operation completes before returning. By completes, I mean to say that for the specific case of local processes, the sender: *(i)* acquires a lock on the message queue of the recipient, *(ii)* writes the message directly into its queue, *(iii)* releases the lock and, *(iv)* finally returns.

I came across this [post](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Lock-free-message-queue-td2550221.html) which I did not fully understand, although it seems to indicate that this could be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erik Stenman's [*The Beam Book*](https://happi.github.io/theBeamBook/), which explains many implementation details of the Erlang VM, answers your question in great detail in its ["Lock Free Message Passing"](https://happi.github.io/theBeamBook/#_lock_free_message_passing) section. The full answer is too long to copy here, but the short answer to your question is that yes, the sending process completely copies its message to a memory area accessible to the receiver. If you consult the book you'll find that it's more complicated than steps *i-iv* you describe in your question due to issues such as different `send` flags, whether locks are already taken by other processes, multiple memory areas, and the state of the receiving process.